# Running a cron job at 11:00 every day?

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks

How do I have to configure a cron job to run every morning at 11:00? I know how to make it run at 11, but not 11:00.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the difference between 11 and 11:00 ?

Answer (score 16):

Linux Crontab Format

```
  MIN HOUR DOM MON DOW CMD

   0 11 * * * filename
```

> **Crontab Fields and Allowed Ranges**
>
> **MIN**   Minute field    0 to 59
>
> **HOUR**  Hour field  0 to 23
>
> **DOM**   Day of Month    1-31
>
> **MON**   Month field     1-12
>
> **DOW**   Day Of Week     0-6
>
> **CMD**   Command     Any command to be executed

For More info: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/